# a link open div (accordion style)

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I just need **div.accordion1** to be opened when I click on **a#accordion1**. Im not an expert on Javascript. I have /wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4 loading on the page trying to use the simple html layout below:

**in the header section:**

```
<div class="header">
    <a href="#accordion1">toggle open / close accordion1</a>
    <a href="#accordion2">toggle open / close accordion2</a>
</div>
```

**positioned somewhere in the body of page:**

```
<div class="body">

    <div class="accordion1">
        Lorem Ipsum....
    </div>

    <div class="accordion2">
        Lorem Ipsum....
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far. We'll gladly help you.

Comment: Your question is unclear, but I assume you want to click on the <a> tag, and then be taken to the section with the class "accordion"?

Comment: Please edit your post with desired behavior.

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: @Adam A - I just need div.accordion to be opened when I click on a#accordion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand right, you want when you press the toggle button, to show a paragraph, and when you click the same button to hide the specific paragraph

here is a good example from w3-schools
https://[www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp)

you have to make a button that calls a function on click

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>


<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
} else {
    x.style.display = "none";
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Yep! Is there a nice "smooth" animation to open/close the div?